# Sending HTTP request using TCP healthcheck

Tags: tcp, haproxy

I have the following config, which is sending a TCP healthcheck to my application (because of the `check` on the last line):

```
backend bk_my-service-9801
  mode tcp
  balance leastconn
  server kube_my-service-0 myhost:31801 check ca-file cicada_CA_renew20220113.pem ssl
```

But these TCP healthchecks are causing 400 entries in my access log:

```
192.123.4.5 - - [21/Feb/2024:10:13:27 +0000] "-" 400 -
```

So I want to update this to send a HTTP HEAD request to / instead of the TCP request (but still using tcp-check instead of httpchk). I have added this using the example at https://docs.haproxy.org/2.8/configuration.html#4-option%20tcp-check:

```
backend bk_my-service-9801
  option tcp-check
  tcp-check connect
  tcp-check send HEAD\ /\ HTTP/1.1\r\n
  tcp-check send User-Agent:\ HAProxy\ tcpcheck\r\n
  tcp-check send \r\n
  tcp-check expect rstring HTTP/1\..\ (2..|3..) comment check\ HTTP\ response
  mode tcp
  balance leastconn
  server kube_my-service-0 myhost:31801 check ca-file cicada_CA_renew20220113.pem ssl
```

but am getting this error:

```
 Layer7 invalid response, info: "TCPCHK did not match content (regex) at step 5 comment: check HTTP response", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

And am still seeing the same 400 entries in the logs even with this added.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use http health check instead of trying to twist tcp health check to do http?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [option httpchk](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.8/configuration.html#4.2-option%20httpchk) as @steffen mentioned with [http-check connect](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.8/configuration.html#4-http-check%20connect).

Here a untested snippet

```
backend bk_my-service-9801
  option httpchk
  http-check connect
  http-check send "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
  http-check send "User-Agent: HAProxy/tcpcheck\r\n"
  http-check send \r\n
  http-check expect rstring "HTTP/1\.. (2..|3..)" comment "check HTTP response"
  mode tcp
  balance leastconn
  server kube_my-service-0 myhost:31801 ..more options
```

A small suggestion, for better readability use `"` where possible, how it works in HAProxy is documented at [Quoting and escaping](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.8/configuration.html#2.2)